# Unity React Native - Android Build - Failed to initialize

Tags: c#, android, react-native, unity-game-engine

I build an Android library from Unity when trying to integrate with React Native app, throwing an error while launching UnityPlayer from React native.

It says your hardware doesn't
support this application.

Unity Version : 2021.3.0f1

Reference Used for Build Library :

https://github.com/asmadsen/react-native-unity-view/blob/master/template/Build.cs

Reference Screenshot :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbmsq.png)

Here is my build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


dependencies {
    implementation ':unity-classes'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 31
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
        versionCode 1
        versionName '0.1'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb', '.unityexp'] + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(', ')
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
        doNotStrip '*/arm64-v8a/*.so'
    }
}

def getSdkDir() {
    Properties local = new Properties()
    local.load(new FileInputStream("${rootDir}/local.properties"))
    return local.getProperty('sdk.dir')
}

def BuildIl2Cpp(String workingDir, String configuration, String architecture, String abi, String[] staticLibraries) {
    def commandLineArgs = []
    commandLineArgs.add("--compile-cpp")
    commandLineArgs.add("--platform=Android")
    commandLineArgs.add("--architecture=" + architecture)
    commandLineArgs.add("--outputpath=" + workingDir + "/src/main/jniLibs/" + abi + "/libil2cpp.so")
    commandLineArgs.add("--libil2cpp-static")
    commandLineArgs.add("--baselib-directory=" + workingDir + "/src/main/jniStaticLibs/" + abi)
    commandLineArgs.add("--configuration=" + configuration)
    commandLineArgs.add("--dotnetprofile=unityaot-linux")
    commandLineArgs.add("--enable-debugger")
    commandLineArgs.add("--profiler-report")
    commandLineArgs.add("--profiler-output-file=" + workingDir + "/build/il2cpp_"+ abi + "_" + configuration + "/il2cpp_conv.traceevents")
    commandLineArgs.add("--print-command-line")
    commandLineArgs.add("--generatedcppdir=" + workingDir + "/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput")
    commandLineArgs.add("--cachedirectory=" + workingDir + "/build/il2cpp_"+ abi + "_" + configuration + "/il2cpp_cache")
    commandLineArgs.add("--tool-chain-path=" + android.ndkDirectory)
    staticLibraries.eachWithIndex {fileName, i->
        commandLineArgs.add("--additional-libraries=" + workingDir + "/src/main/jniStaticLibs/" + abi + "/" + fileName)
    }
    def executableExtension = ""
    if (org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current().isWindows())
        executableExtension = ".exe"
    exec {
        executable workingDir + "/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/build/deploy/il2cpp" + executableExtension
        args commandLineArgs
        environment "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT", getSdkDir()
    }
    delete workingDir + "/src/main/jniLibs/" + abi + "/libil2cpp.sym.so"
    ant.move(file: workingDir + "/src/main/jniLibs/" + abi + "/libil2cpp.dbg.so", tofile: workingDir + "/symbols/" + abi + "/libil2cpp.so")
}

android {
    task BuildIl2CppTask {
        doLast {
              BuildIl2Cpp(projectDir.toString().replaceAll('\\\\', '/'), 'Release', 'armv7', 'armeabi-v7a', [  ] as String[]);
              BuildIl2Cpp(projectDir.toString().replaceAll('\\\\', '/'), 'Release', 'arm64', 'arm64-v8a', [  ] as String[]);
        }
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        if (project(':unityLibrary').tasks.findByName('mergeDebugJniLibFolders'))
            project(':unityLibrary').mergeDebugJniLibFolders.dependsOn BuildIl2CppTask
        if (project(':unityLibrary').tasks.findByName('mergeReleaseJniLibFolders'))
            project(':unityLibrary').mergeReleaseJniLibFolders.dependsOn BuildIl2CppTask
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = ["src/main/Il2CppOutputProject"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]